# Exporting all Marketo Leads in a CSV?

Tags: marketo

I am trying to export all of my leads from Marketo (we have over 20M+) into a CSV file, but there is a 10k row limit per CSV export.

Is there any other way that I can export a CSV file with more than 10k row? I tried searching for various dataloader tool on Marketo Launchpoint but couldn't find a tool that would work.

Comment: did you find a solution to this? I'd like to do the same.

Comment: Are you looking to export your Leads in order to migrate them to a new marketing tool?

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using the API? It may not be practical unless you have a developer on your team (I'm a programmer).

[marketo lead api](http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/rest/get-multiple-leads-by-list-id)

Answer (score 0):

If your leads are in salesforce and marketo/salesforce are in parity, instead of exporting all your leads, do a sync from salesforce to the new MA tool (if you are switching) instead. It's a cleaner easier sync.
For important campaigns etc, you can create smart lists and export those.

Answer (score 0):

There is no 10k row limit for exporting Leads from a list. However, there is a practical limit, especially if you choose to export all columns (instead of only the visible columns). I would generally advise on exporting a maximum of 200,000-300,000 leads per list, so you'd need to create multiple Lists.

As Michael mentioned, the API is also a good option. I would still advise to create multiple Lists, so you can run multiple processes in parallel, which will speed things up. You will need to look at your daily API quota: the default is either 10,000 or 50,000. 10,000 API calls allow you to download 3 million Leads (batch size 300).

Answer (score 0):

I am trying out Data Loader for Marketo on Marketo Launchpoint to export my lead and activity data to my local database. Although it cannot transfer marketo data to CSV file directly, you can download Lead to your local database and then export to get a CSV file. For your reference, we have 100K leads and 1 billion activity data.
You might have to run multiple times for 20M leads, but the tool is quite easy and convenient to use so maybe it’s worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

Initially there are 4 steps to get bulk leads from marketo
1. Creating a Job 
2. Enqueue Export Lead Job
2. Polling Job Status
3. Retrieving Your Data

http://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/bulk-extract/bulk-lead-extract/